# With #container div make child stretch to full width centering content

Tags: html, css, layout, width, background-color

this is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

I already know positioning, centering and stuff. The problem I have here, and which I want to ask you guys, is: what's the **best practise** to have a centered div and everything inside it to be centered while having a single one's background color exceed to the full width of the page always keeping it centered?

It's a super common layout in fact, I just don't know what's the correct way of "thinking" it.

Should I think the layout as "I make a big box with 1280px width, center it with margin: 0 auto; and then do something special for that div's background - and only the background, content should stay in place - to exceed or should I make something like a class to center every single element the same way but repeating my code?

So basically, should be all inside a single box and that div exceed in the background only or it's actually better to center everything separately by repeating the code?

Keep in mind the site is **not responsive and doesn't need to adapt/scale** and also that the light grey area is also the "body" colore so the dark grey area is the only special case in the page that should exceed.

Comment: I had trouble reading the first paragraph, but how you'd like to position containing elements depends a lot on what's most convenient for the specific site. I like assigning a "base" class to the most common 1280px box, then branching out with classes that have more specific styles.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try to think the layout like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

I would create three basic containers for the full width support. Then nest content in it!

[image]

```css
        html, body{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0; /*ie older versions*/
        }
        header {
            background-color: antiquewhite;
        }
        section{
            background-color: ActiveCaption;
        }
        footer{
            background-color: aquamarine;
        }
        .inner-wrapper{
            max-width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
            height: 80px; 
            text-align: center;
        }

        section .inner-wrapper{
            height: 200px;
        }
```

```html
         <header>
            <div class="inner-wrapper">
                <div>some content</div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div class="inner-wrapper">
                <div>some content</div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <div class="inner-wrapper">
                <div>some content</div>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

This is a absolut basic but robust layout an i used it several times. It is very easy to make it responsive with media queries or fluid with percentage settings!

Comment: I tried it and it worked, this really is the most simple way of thinking about it probably! Thank you for the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should give to the body or to a container div the `background` color property and that div to be full width and height then the div that is in the middle you should give a `margin:0 auto;` and a specific width, this is what I would do, but it depends on what you are trying to do, what is the most common way you do it in order to you to know to how to do it the same next time, faster.

Comment: Yep that seems what I needed. I was struggling to know if there was a better way than the ones I was using and this seems the "lighter" one...thanks!

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer was the most suitable.